# Port-forwarding with Authentication

Tags: router, authentication, port-forwarding

Okay, so here's the story:

I administrate a server running a web application on my internal LAN, say foo:1234. My team uses this actively.

We have now decided to make this application accessible from outside our network - but we don't want to install it on our webserver. I have forwarded an external port (say 5678) on our (DDWRT) router to foo:1234, and this works fine.

The problem though, is that due to certain configuration issues anyone can view the page without being logged in, if they know the URL. I want to prevent that in some way.

I created a page (with login) on our web server, that redirects to router:5678 after authentication, but that's not really a solution; router:5678 is still publicly accessible.

My question: How can I set it up so that the port gets forwarded only after authentication?

Comment: What model of router/firewall are you using?

Comment: ddwrt - just added that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to handle this situation is to place an authenticating reverse proxy (e.g., apache) in front of the web server.

See e.g. http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/reverse-proxy-with-apache/